# Catch validation rule error in apex and show in lwc

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, validation-rule

I have a validation rule which is stopping my record to get updated. I have to send just that specific validation error and display in lwc.
Apex code:`

```
    }catch(Exception e){
        
        throw new AuraHandledException(e.getMessage());
    }
    `
```

LWC code:

```
.catch(error => {
            console.log("error"+error.body.message)
```

When I see in the console I see the message as "Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id a0v1g000003PxkAAAS; first error: FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION, This seat is already matched to another student. Please remove the existing match before matching this student."

I don't want to display as this as it is not good user experience, I would just like to display the validation rule error message "This seat is already matched to another student. Please remove the existing match before matching this student."

is there any way to do this?

Comment: how it got resolved? I am also facing same problem to diplay validatipn message on lwc page

Comment: @RaviJakhotiya Did sfdcfox's answer not work for you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's the message you get from DmlException. If you want to get just the actual message, you need to use:

```
Database.SaveResult[] results = Database.update(records, false);
for(Database.SaveResult result: results) {
  if(!result.isSuccess()) {
    throw new AuraHandledException(result.getErrors()[0].getMessage());
  }
}
```

By throwing the exception, you'll revert all changes, but you'll have just the error message you want. You could also encode all the errors and display as many as you need in the UI. The [Database.SaveResult](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_database_saveresult.htm#apex_methods_system_database_saveresult) class gives you all the information you'd want to know to display to the user.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It helped to fix the issue.

Answer (score -1):

The code below makes sure you will see all the validation rule messages

```
try{}
catch(DMLException e){
    for (Integer i = 0; i < e.getNumDml(); i++) {
        System.debug(e.getDmlMessage(i)); 
    }
}
```